# Why is SQL Server providing a syntax error when it was working perfectly fine in Aginity/Redshift environment?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    SUM(extended_amount) AS total_spent,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(client_web_order_number)) AS #_of_orders,
    MAX(oms_order_date) AS last_purchase_date,
    (CURRENT_DATE - last_purchase_date) AS days_since_last_purchase,
    MIN(oms_order_date) AS registration_date,
    (CURRENT_DATE - registration_date) AS days_active,
    CASE
        WHEN (days_since_last_purchase = days_active) THEN 'One-time purchase'
        ELSE ''
    END AS notes

FROM 
    mdwh.us_raw.l_dmw_order_report

WHERE 
    quantity_ordered > 0
    AND customer_id IS NOT NULL
    AND customer_id != ('')
    AND customer_id LIKE 'US%'
    AND oms_order_date IS NOT NULL
    AND UPPER(line_status) NOT IN ('','RETURN', 'CANCELLED')
    AND UPPER(item_description_1) NOT IN ('','FREIGHT', 'RETURN LABEL FEE', 'VISIBLE STITCH')
    AND (quantity_ordered * unit_price_amount) > 0
    AND extended_amount < 1000 --NO BULK ORDERS
    AND oms_order_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND CURRENT_DATE
    AND SUBSTRING(upc,1,6) IN (SELECT item_code FROM item_master_zs WHERE new_division BETWEEN '11' AND '39')

GROUP BY
    customer_id
--HAVING
--  SUM(extended_amount) BETWEEN 1 AND 50
```

Here's the error message:
[image]

I've tried renaming the source in the query, updating SQL Server settings to the primary source.

This was a poor question, which I realize now. Will not delete, but tried my best to improve. Thank you for your help, everyone.

Comment: Do you realize that '2' is between '11' and '39'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the syntax for date arithmetics to make the query valid in SQL Server. Also, you cannot access expressions declared in the `SELECT` clause in other columns, you need to repeat the expression.

So you want to change the `SELECT` clause to:

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    SUM(extended_amount) AS total_spent,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(client_web_order_number)) AS #_of_orders,
    MAX(oms_order_date) AS last_purchase_date,
    DATEDIFF(day, last_purchase_date, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))  AS days_since_last_purchase,
    MIN(oms_order_date) AS registration_date,
    DATEDIFF(day, registration_date, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS days_active,
    CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, last_purchase_date, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) 
            = DATEDIFF(day, registration_date, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) 
        THEN 'One-time purchase'
        ELSE ''
    END AS notes
FROM ...
```